# How can I neatly time if something works?

Tags: c#

Currently I am using the following:

```
Stopwatch stopWatchB = new Stopwatch();
stopWatchB.Start();
_callIndex.Test = _callTable.Get(u => u.PartitionKey == _callIndex.PageMeta.User & u.RowKey == "A");
stopWatchB.Stop();
em1 = stopWatchB.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```

My code works great but looks so messy. Stopwatches starting and stopping :-(  Is there any way that I could clean this up. Note that I can't change the .Get() method and the data returned to _callIndex.Test is a class called Test that has multiple fields.

Comment: `looks so messy` No it doesn't.

Comment: I don't think that looks messy at all. Except for the call to the .Get() method, which you can't change.

Comment: Concur with StuperUser - why do you think this looks messy?

Comment: The thing is I like to encapsulate and reuse. Every time I have calls the get data I have all these stopwatch calls. In this case it's 4 lines for the stopwatch and one for actually getting the data.

Comment: AFAIK, the best way to see elapsed time is by using `Stopwatch`. I do it all the time whenever needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, to start with you can use:

```
Stopwatch stopWatchB = Stopwatch.StartNew();
```

You could also take the `ElapsedMilliseconds` without stopping it first, if you wanted:

```
Stopwatch stopWatchB = Stopwatch.StartNew();
_callIndex.Test = _callTable.Get(
     u => u.PartitionKey == _callIndex.PageMeta.User & u.RowKey == "A");
em1 = stopWatchB.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```

That's a bit simpler. Alternatively, you could create a helper method:

```
public static TimeSpan Time(Action action)
{
    Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    action();
    return stopwatch.Elapsed;
}
```

Then:

```
em1 = StopwatchHelper.Time(() => {
    _callIndex.Test = _callTable.Get(
         u => u.PartitionKey == _callIndex.PageMeta.User & u.RowKey == "A");
}).TotalMilliseconds;
```

Comment: @Daniel: Than my first option or the second? It's unfortunate that the action being timed here has side-effects... in this case I prefer my first option, but for a smaller action I'd probably go for the second.

Comment: take a look at my answer, let me know what you think

Comment: Is possible to create a solution similar to the second option using an attribute?

Comment: @StuperUser: An attribute where?

Comment: @Fredou: Well it wouldn't end up storing the result in `em1` for starters... so it's not equivalent. I'm not sure about using `using` statements like that, when there's nothing to really clean up...

Comment: THANK YOU JON !!   I knew it must be possible to make it look a lot cleaner and you easily proved it could !!

Comment: I didn't saw that "return time", maybe a oops is needed on my side, fixed it now

Comment: @Jon: I meant cleaner than the second. But this might only be because of the formating.

Comment: @Daniel: Yes, Stack Overflow's limited width can definitely make a difference to cleanliness :)

Comment: @Jon, I was assuming that a this code was in a method was being timed, would it be possible to use an attribute that refers to a method uses `Elapsed` to e.g. log execution time.

Comment: @StuperUser: But how would you tell it to only time *part* of the method call? If you were timing the *whole* of the method call then you could possibly do it using PostSharp or something similar.

Comment: @Jon, was assuming it would have to be the whole method, I'll check out PostSharp. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I use this to do "benchmark"

for using it:

```
using(var b = new bench())
{
     //stuff
     em1 = b.ElapsedMilliseconds;
}
```

///

```
class bench : Stopwatch, IDisposable
{
    private static bool enabled = true;

    public static bool Enabled
    {
        get { return enabled; }
        set { enabled = value; }
    }

    private string func;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="bench"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public bench()
    {
        begin("", false, false);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="bench"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="showStack">if set to <c>true</c> [show stack].</param>
    public bench(bool showStack)
    {
        begin("", showStack, false);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="bench"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="showStack">if set to <c>true</c> [show stack].</param>
    /// <param name="showStart">if set to <c>true</c> [show start].</param>
    public bench(bool showStack, bool showStart)
    {
        begin("", showStack, showStart);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="bench"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="func">The func.</param>
    public bench(String func)
    {
        begin(func, false, false);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="bench"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="func">The func.</param>
    /// <param name="showStack">if set to <c>true</c> [show stack].</param>
    public bench(String func, bool showStack)
    {
        begin(func, showStack, false);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="bench"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="func">The func.</param>
    /// <param name="showStack">if set to <c>true</c> [show stack].</param>
    /// <param name="showStart">if set to <c>true</c> [show start].</param>
    public bench(String func, bool showStack, bool showStart)
    {
        begin(func, showStack, showStart);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Begins the specified func.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="func">The func.</param>
    /// <param name="showStack">if set to <c>true</c> [show stack].</param>
    /// <param name="showStart">if set to <c>true</c> [show start].</param>
    private void begin(String func, bool showStack, bool showStart)
    {
        if (bench.Enabled)
        { 
            this.func = func;

            if (showStack || showStart)
                Debug.WriteLine("Start " + func);

            if (showStack)
                Debug.WriteLine("Stack: " + Environment.StackTrace);

            this.Start();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Performs application-defined tasks associated with freeing, releasing, or resetting unmanaged resources.
    /// </summary>
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (bench.Enabled || this.IsRunning)
        {
            this.Stop();

            if (bench.Enabled)
            { 
                Debug.WriteLine("Stop " + func + " " + Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString("0.#######") + " seconds");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a class that implements IDisposable, and starts a stopwatch on creation, stopping it when disposed.

You can create a class that manages such items, as in my code here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410569/speeding-up-performance-monitoring-code

It does quite a bit more than you ask (handling timing 'child' code and rendering timing values), however you can hopefully get the basic idea.

EDIT: For a simple example, see @Fredou's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the class which starts Stopwatch in the constructor and stops in the Dispose() (obviously you have to implement IDisposable).

```
using (var profiler = new PerformanceProfiler(out elapsedMilliseconds)
{
    // profiled action code ...
}

Debug.WriteLine(elapsedMilliseconds.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));
```